# Loading external resourceBundle from dependency

Tags: java, maven, resourcebundle

I have a base framework (call it 'A') that contains resourceBundles for localization support. In a new project, I'm using A as a maven dependency in order to gain access to it's functionalities.

However, it seems that when I'm trying to load the resourceBundle in my new project, it is unable to find it in the dependency and throws `Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name`.

Is it possible to load such resourceBundles from external dependencies, or should I move it from A to my new project and keep it there? The reason we want to keep it in A is because we want to use A in multiple projects and maintaining the bundles would be much easier.

Edit: this is how I'm storing and loading the bundle:

Artifact A has the bundle here:

```
src/main/java/localizationManagement/BundleENStrings.java
```

Artifact A also contains the following base class for tests (all test classes extend this class in the new project):

```
src/main/java/testManagement/UtilityTestClass.java
```

Default locale is initialized here as follows:

```
resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/main/java/localizationManagement/BundleENStrings.java")
```

This works just right while I'm working on Artifact A's code, but when I try to run a test in the new project, that extends the above mentioned `UtilityTestClass` it will fail to find the `BundleENStrings.java`

Even if I try to manually load the resource bundle in the class that extends UtilityTestClass I will get the same error. I also tried to use the following path method:

```
jetbrains://idea/navigate/reference?project=project-name&fqn=localizationManagement.BundleENStrings
```

I'm assuming I should somehow modify the fqn parameter value to point to the dependency jar.

Comment: Should be possible, but without some snippet of code (how do you load your bundles?) hard to answer

Comment: I added additional info to the question, hope it clears things up.

Comment: This is a rather strange setup. Does "BundleENStrings.java" denote a java source file? Usually, one would expect resource bundles to be located under src/main/resources. And never reference anything under "src/..." on runtime, i would rather expect "localizationManagement/BundleENStrings.java" as path for getBundle()

Comment: Yes, it is a class that extends ListResourceBundle. If I understood correctly, I can either use this solution or create a bundle.properties file and just list a = b value pairs there. But moving the BundleENStrings.java to resources didn't help either.

Comment: OK, so if it is java file, it belongs to src/java to get compiled. But you would rather reference it as "localizationManagement/BundleENStrings"

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I had to use localizationManagement.BundleENStrings, with a '.' not a '/'

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Try to work with class*/  

package com.example.languages;
import java.util.ListResourceBundle;
public class ResourceBundle extends ListResourceBundle {
    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][]{
            {"lang.en", "English"},
            {"lnag.de", "German"},
            {"lang.es", "Spanish"},
            {"lang.fr", "French"},
            {"lang.pt", "Portuguese"},
            {"lang.ru", "Russian"},
            {"lang.it", "italian"},
            {"lang.jp", "japanese"},
            {"lang.cn", "Chinese"}        
         };
    }
}
// in another class
package com.exemplo;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ExemploResourceBundleWithClass {
    /* package by are the classes*/
    static final String pack= "com.exemplo.languages";
    static final String baseName = "ResourceBundle";
    static final String path = pack+"."+baseName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle(path);
        //or 
        ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.exemplo.languages.ResourceBundle");
    }


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).